# I did a PhoneGap app that starts the camera, a picture is taken and saved to sdcard. How do I get that picture to show it in HTML?

Tags: android, image, cordova

I did a PhoneGap Android app that starts the camera, a picture is taken and saved to sdcard. The app shows the picture on the initial screen. The app also allows to navigate through some additional web pages. If I navigate away (to another web page) and come back to the first screen, the picture is no longer there. I tried to get it from the sdcard and show it using the HTML  tag, to be seen even before another picture is taken, but the picture is not shown (I see the "alt" text instead).

I am not sure whether my problem is clear, but I am ready to answer your questions to clarify it.

My project is in the GitHub at the address https://github.com/monicamarcus/Android_PhoneGap

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

The Javascript that shows the picture the first time:

```
//Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
 var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
smallImage.style.display = 'block'
smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
```

Comment: How is the image displayed the first time?

Comment: Using HTML <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></img> which is inside a <div id="camera">  and using also a JavaScript function. I shall add the code of the function to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) { 
    localStorage.img="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData;
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
   smallImage.src= localStorage.img;
   smallImage.style.display = 'block'; 
   }



document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
if(typeof(localStorage.img)!='undefined'){
smallImage=document.getElementById('cameraPic');
smallImage.src=localStorage.img;
smallImage.style.display='block';
}
},false);
```

Comment: Thank you Vicky Gonsalves, but it does not work. With this change I don't even see the picture for the first time (where the picture should be I only see a tiny small -- very small -- rectangle.)

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problem. Now I can see the picture on the initial screen, but if I navigate to another web page of the app, when I come back to the original screen there is no picture

Comment: I should add that I can see the picture in /storage/sdcard0, but when I try to view it from sdcard it says "unable to load photo".

Comment: Can you look in the GitHub? I posted the link in my initial question.

Comment: there are errors in your index.html and navigation.js file also i cant see phonegap.js file in the project..use better editor to code...:) i run the above solution in your code and it worked as requied...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39518/discussion-between-monica-and-vicky-gonsalves)

Comment: I spotted a mistake in index.html, I know the file phonegap.js does not exist (I followed an example HelloWorld from PhoneGap to write my application) but I don't know what mistakes there are in the navigatiom.js file. Will you please give me more details about your foundings? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am very disappointed, Vicky Gonsalves. I thought you are willing to help me solve my problem.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply. Check your chat

Comment: I'm fine, it finally works, using the code suggested by Vicky Gonzales. THanks!

Comment: I am very disappointed, Monica. I thought u ll upvote and flag it correct code :(( Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about this. But I did it just now.

Comment: I apologize also for misspelling your last name, but it happened only once.